# Ember.js form validations with ember-cp-validations

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am currently working with a team on an Ember application which needs form validations. We decided to use [ember-cp-validations](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations) 
for the front-end form validations. I am trying to follow the example they have to add some simple validations, but for some reason the validation messages aren't showing. I created a separate file called `preprint-form-validator.js` which contains the basic validations using `buildValidations`.

Then in my data model, I imported the file:

`import Validations from '../validators/preprint-form-validator';`

and extended the model with it so that the model knew that there should be validations for some of its fields:

`export default DS.Model.extend(Validations, { ...`

After I did that, I followed the example and created the validated-input component. These files can be found [here](http://offirgolan.github.io/ember-cp-validations/) and they create the front-end framework for what the validated form inputs should look like.

Finally, in my component, I included the new validated-input component:

`{{validated-input model=model valuePath="title" placeholder="Title"}}`

When I go to the page with the validator, there is an input field that doesn't really do anything -- as in it does not validate or check any of the restrictions that I tried to include. In the route that the component is in, I have a model hook that does a `createRecord()` like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.createRecord('preprint');
    }
});
```

When I was trying to solve the issue, I believe it's something to do with the model or that somehow the `validation` property wasn't being set in validated-input.js.

However at this point I got stuck and could not figure out what was wrong with my form validation.

It seems like I'm missing some crucial connection in this form validation, but I'm not sure what it is. I would appreciate if anyone could give guidance on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In our application we used this as ember validations straight and easy to use. https://github.com/DockYard/ember-validations

Answer (score 0):

Can't see nothing wrong with your code. What does your "preprint-form-validator" looks like? You can validate a form component if you like too.

```
//login-form.js
import { LoginValidations } from '../../validators/login-validator';

export default Ember.Component.extend(LoginValidations, {
  isValid: Ember.computed.and('validations.isValid'),
});

//login-form.hbs

{{validated-input type="email" model=this valuePath="email"}}
{{validated-input type="password" model=this valuePath="password"}}

//validators/login-validator.js
import { validator, buildValidations } from 'ember-cp-validations';

export const LoginValidations = buildValidations({
email: [
  validator('presence', {
    presence: true,
    message: 'O email deve ser informado'
  }),
validator('format', {
  type: 'email',
  message: 'Email inválido'
})
],

password: [
  validator('presence', {
    presence: true,
    message: 'A senha deve ser informada'
  }),
  validator('length', {
    min: 6,
    message: 'A senha deve possuir no mínimo 6 caracteres'
  }),    
  validator('password-validator')
]
});

export default { LoginValidations };
```